# OEM Debian GNU/Linux installation

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I have been asked to install Debian GNU/Linux on 100 computers some time ago. Today I received one hundred labels like this

[image: Debian COA example] (digital image made from SVG attachment from email asking me to install Debian)

and one Debian installation DVD. However, I don't know how should I *OEM install* them so user will be able to create own account and configure the system before starting to work because Debian installer only provides standard install.

How do I *OEM install* Debian? What should I do with these labels?

Comment: Related to the labels: https://serverfault.com/questions/986224/purchasing-a-license-for-enterprise-gnu-linux and https://serverfault.com/questions/992485/strange-labels-on-our-servers

Comment: @Freddy so I was scammed?

Comment: At least this `glat-client` seems dubious. Maybe it's just a hoax, maybe scam. Don't install such software.

Comment: What should I do with these labels?

Comment: GLAT is a scam and needs to be shut down.

Comment: Notice that the maintainer of the notabug site had posted a commit to the README file on there saying "Add that this is satire" -- commit 9ccade766a -- which was later reverted as "Remove defacement" (I won't link to the site).

Answer (score 5):

It appears the GLAT scam has migrated to using pictures of the URL instead of the URL directly, and that they are temporarily hosted at notabug.org instead of on github/gitlab as before. I would throw the stickers away and install Debian by following [Debian's Installation instructions](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/installmanual).

---

Quoting [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) from the [Server Fault page: Purchasing a license for enterprise GNU/Linux](https://serverfault.com/a/986254/293440):

> You should remove this `glat-client` from your affected systems, and treat this as a potential security compromise.
>
> Looking at the source code repositories for this so-called [glat-official](https://gitlab.com/glat-official), we can see that they are based on the so-called [Linux Genuine Advantage](http://www.linuxgenuineadvantage.org/faq/), a hoax licensing scheme for Linux which was meant as a parody of [Windows Genuine Advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Genuine_Advantage) (a Windows technology in Windows XP that was infamous for annoying legitimate users). Linux Genuine Advantage did not actually do anything, but it appears that someone has made this GLAT have a functional license server. Whoever they are, they might even be trying to collect money from people. If that's the case, it would be more of a scam than a hoax.
>
> In either case, you should investigate how this program got on to your systems, as it may be an indication of security compromise.